# trim string without error even when its null or undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have been wondering whether it is possible without a helper function to trim an attribute that can be a string or alternatively `undefined` or `null` without `try..catch`.

`(obj.postcode || "").trim()` is the simplest way I could come up with. Is there a different way to do it?

```
const obj = {}
const inParams = []
const postcode = (obj.postcode || "").trim()
if (!postcode) {
  inParams.push('zip:'+ postcode)
}
```

Comment: There is a proposal for [`obj.postcode?.trim()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) but for now  you could either use `||` or ternary `obj.postcode ? obj.postcode.trim(): void 0`

Comment: Thank you @YuryTarabanko for the hint regarding optional chaining. Sadly I cant use it in my current context.

Comment: what's the point of pushing postcode if `!postcode`? This would be satisfied only for `postcode === ""`

Comment: If you are using babel there is a [plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) to enable this syntax. Also you might want to take a look at [idx.macro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idx.macro)

Comment: @barbsan The negation covers alls falsy values https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: I know, but in case of falsy value you'll get `""` in previous line.

Comment: @barbsan I was looking for different ways to do it than `(obj.postcode || "")` so consider it a bad example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to check if `obj.postcode` exists.

Try:

```
const postcode = (obj.postcode) ? obj.postcode.trim() : "";
```

Comment: OP is doing that check.

Answer (score 2):

Try this it works well...

```
my_str = ....
my_str = (typeof my_str === 'string')? my_str.trim() : '';
```